# How to set Datatype in Additional Column in ADF

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory

I need to set datatype for Additional Column with Dynamic Content in Sink in ADF

**By default its taking nvarchar(max) from Json obj but I need bigInt**

Below is a Json Obj which create table with Additional column

```
{
    "source": {
        "type": "SqlServerSource",
         "additionalColumns": [
            {
                "name": "ApplicationId",
                "value": 3604509277250831000
            }
        ],
        "sqlReaderQuery": "SELECT * from Table A",
        "queryTimeout": "02:00:00",
        "isolationLevel": "ReadUncommitted",
        "partitionOption": "None"
    },
    "sink": {
        "type": "AzureSqlSink",
        "writeBehavior": "insert",
        "sqlWriterUseTableLock": false,
        "tableOption": "autoCreate",
        "disableMetricsCollection": false
    },
    "enableStaging": false,
    "translator": {
        "type": "TabularTranslator",
        "typeConversion": true,
        "typeConversionSettings": {
            "allowDataTruncation": true,
            "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
        }
    }
}
```

**ADF Configuration**

[image]

**After create table Database -  column with datatype**

[image]

**If I convert Dynamic content into Int**

```
@int(pipeline().parameters.application.applicationId)
```

Then getting below warning

[image]

Please let me know how can I set Datatype in ADF

Comment: How is the pipeline parameter defined? If it is defined as a string, try converting it to an int: @int(INSERT_YOUR_PARAMETER_REFERENCE_HERE)

Comment: go to Mapping >> Import Schema >> select `Int64` as type of additional column. as shown in this [image](https://i.imgur.com/nTxibZA.png)

Comment: JoelCochran 
Getting Warning - 

Expression of type: 'Int' does not match the field: 'value'

@int(pipeline().parameters.application.applicationId)

Comment: Pratik - This is a Additional Column.
Not getting from Source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also tried the same and getting same result.

[image]

> **By default its taking nvarchar(max) from Json obj but I need bigInt**

To resolve this when you add additional column in your source data set and in `Mapping` click on`import schema` it will import the schema of the source and also give you additional column in schema you have to change the type of the column as `Int64` as shown in below image. in below image you can see after `name` there is additional means it is an additional column.

[image]

After this run your pipeline, It will create additional column with data type `bigint` .

```json
{
    "name": "pipeline2",
    "properties": {
    "activities": [
    {
    "name": "Copy data1",
    "type": "Copy",
    "dependsOn": [],
    "policy": {
    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
    "retry": 0,
    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
    "secureOutput": false,
    "secureInput": false
    },
    "userProperties": [],
    "typeProperties": {
    "source": {
    "type": "JsonSource",
    "additionalColumns": [
    {
    "name": "name",
    "value": {
    "value": "@pipeline().parameters.demo.age",
    "type": "Expression"
    }
    }
    ],
    "storeSettings": {
    "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
    "recursive": true,
    "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
    },
    "formatSettings": {
    "type": "JsonReadSettings"
    }
    },
    "sink": {
    "type": "AzureSqlSink",
    "writeBehavior": "insert",
    "sqlWriterUseTableLock": false,
    "tableOption": "autoCreate",
    "disableMetricsCollection": false
    },
    "enableStaging": false,
    "translator": {
    "type": "TabularTranslator",
    "mappings": [
    {
    "source": {
    "path": "$['taskId']"
    },
    "sink": {
    "name": "taskId",
    "type": "String"
    }
    },
    {
    "source": {
    "path": "$['taskObtainedScore']"
    },
    "sink": {
    "name": "taskObtainedScore",
    "type": "String"
    }
    },
    {
    "source": {
    "path": "$['multiInstance']"
    },
    "sink": {
    "name": "multiInstance",
    "type": "String"
    }
    },
    {
    "source": {
    "path": "$['name']"
    },
    "sink": {
    "name": "name",
    "type": "Int64"
    }
    }
    ],
    "collectionReference": ""
    }
    },
    "inputs": [
    {
    "referenceName": "Json1",
    "type": "DatasetReference"
    }
    ],
    "outputs": [
    {
    "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable1",
    "type": "DatasetReference"
    }
    ]
    }
    ],
    "parameters": {
    "demo": {
    "type": "object",
    "defaultValue": {
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30,
    "isStudent": true
    }
    }
    },
    "annotations": []
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]